# What is a tower crane in German

Tags: single-word-request, noun

What do you call *tower crane* in German? It is a noun.

[image: Image of a tower crane]

I found a corresponding Wikipedia page named [Kran](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kran). I am now wondering whether to use *Kran, Drehkran* or *Turmdrehkran.*

My hypothesis: *Kran* is a hypernym, *Turmdrehkran* is what I am looking for.

Comment: Wow, I learned a lot: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turmkran

Answer (score 12):

Most of the population — especially small children who are generally fascinated by construction sites — would not think twice and call the thing in the image a *Kran.*

However, you are correct that the word *Kran* is indeed a hypernym and can subsume different types of cranes. If you want to be 100 % specific, use *Turmkran* or *Turmdrehkran.* Do not use those terms outside of industry fairs or specialised companies that sell, rent or buy these things as you will be looked at with confusion. (‘Ach, Sie meinen *Kran!’)*

Comment: I believe the same is true for the English words "crane vs. tower crane"!?

Comment: @user1583209 *Very* likely; although I didn’t use *crane* in English as much as I did *Kran* in German.

Answer (score 4):

Your thesis turns out to be right. There are various kinds of cranes whose names contain "Kran".

For example, [Fahrzeugkran](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fahrzeugkran)

The word you are looking for is [*Turmkran*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turmkran)

Comment: or alternatively: *Turmdrehkran*

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question: Basically, you are right.

*However*, note that outside of professional circles, *Turmdrehkran* and *Drehkran* may not be known.

On the other hand, it is my impression that when you say *Kran*, the first association that most people will have *is* that of a tower crane. Rather than *Drehkran*, the word *Mobilkran* (mobile crane) will be commonly understood. Therefore, you could say that if a *Kran* is not explicitly called *Mobilkran*, the default assumption will be that you are talking about a tower crane.